# Our third party javascript dependency exports a default object that's 50KB, how to get webpack to only include part of the object in the bundle?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Our code depends on the `streamlinehq/streamline-regular` javascript package. This package is both third party, and proprietary, meaning that we can not fork it nor edit it.

We have `debug.js` example code like so:

```
import MessagesSpeechBubbles from '@streamlinehq/streamline-regular/lib/messages-chat-smileys/MessagesSpeechBubbles';
window.console.log(MessagesSpeechBubbles.MessagesBubbleSquareText);
```

Looking at MessagesSpeechBubbles js file, it is exporting a massive default object with SVG data for each different type of speech bubble, totaling 50kb after minification. For reference see the output of bundle analysis:

[image: bundle analysis showing a 50kb import after minification]

Is there some way to import or bring in this object partially, such that after being bundled by webpack, only the `MessagesBubbleSquareText` part of the object would be included in the final bundle?

Essentially is there some way we can shrink our production bundle by only including SVG data that we're actually using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to split apart objects with some kind of tree shaking in javascript. Tree shaking can only make it so that only the objects and functions that are necessary are included in the production bundle, but if you have a giant "mega object" that you import, it can't include only part of it.

In order to make your libraries practical to use, it's important to write them such that they export a number of small objects, rather than one big giant default object.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have an account there, but if they implemented tree shaking the right way you may try:

```
import { MessagesBubbleSquareText } from '@streamlinehq/streamline-regular';
window.console.log(MessagesBubbleSquareText);
```

or something like that. don't know how the import works as i can't find a gitrepo for this npm package

Comment: Yes, if they exported each SVG as a separate named object, rather than as a nested default object, you could simply do that. However they don't export things using best practices, and so your code snippet just logs "undefined" because there's no named object "MessagesBubbleSquareText"

Comment: maybe you should open an issue on there library. i don't think you can do anything else. maybe there is some dirty hack to webpack. the other solution would be to copy the svg to your own project and embed it form there.

Comment: We did that. We heard back from them: "Yeah, there's a plan to be able to tree shake the package. Beginning Q4 20 as we'll add hundreds of new icons." Until then though unfortunately this problem seems intractable.